# Automating Report Generation and Delivery without admin permission

Tags: sql, python-3.x, excel, automation, powerbi

I have a SQL script that generates a report for me (it can also be generated in PowerBi or Excel).
I want this report to be generated every half hour and sent to me by email, **regardless of whether the computer is turned on or not.**
The problem is that I work in a bank and I do not have administrator rights, so I cannot install new applications.
I have Python 3 without libraries, PowerBi, Excel, SQL, and internet access.

I have reached the point where I load the script into Excel, and with the help of a macro, it updates and sends it to email, but this only works when the computer is turned on.
How can I do the same thing with the computer turned off?